# How can I get the list of availbale notifications in iOS?

Tags: ios, notifications

In one of my application I want to handle email/call/sms notifications. How can I achieve the same also how can I get the list of available notifications in iOS?

Answer (score 1):

You can't, there is not API that allows you to do this.

When a user click on a notification you app is informed only about the notification that the user clicked on. You are not able to see if there are any notification for your app, let alone  for any other app.

Comment: But I looked after the another apps that do the same thing and get the notifications/alerts like Cookoo. Check the app store for the same and suggest me.

Comment: No sure how they do it, but it is in the bluuetooth stack not in there app. Read the [Local Notifications and Push Notifications](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Introduction.html) you will see that there is not option to read the notification. Especial to from other apps.